# 足って used in Ponyo Song

Tags: grammar, conjugations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are these forms: かけちゃお, つないじゃお?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/what-are-these-forms-%e3%81%8b%e3%81%91%e3%81%a1%e3%82%83%e3%81%8a-%e3%81%a4%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e3%81%98%e3%82%83%e3%81%8a)
>   [Is this って　equivalent to 「と」？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6541/is-this-%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6%e3%80%80equivalent-to-%e3%80%8c%e3%81%a8%e3%80%8d%ef%bc%9f)

From the Ponyo theme song:

```
ペータペタ ピョーンピョン 
足っていいな かけちゃお!
```

Why is 足 given the て conjugation, as if it's a verb? I usually only see that for 足る, which has nothing to do with feet. What's going on here grammatically?

Comment: How does it read? あし? はし?

Comment: oops sorry, I accidentally voted to close it as a duplicate of [What are these forms: かけちゃお, つないじゃお?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/) (it's a question about the same verse but doesn't answer this one). But I think it's a duplicate of [Is this って　equivalent to 「と」？](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6541/is-this-%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%80%80equivalent-to-%E3%80%8C%E3%81%A8%E3%80%8D%EF%BC%9F)

Comment: fefe, it's read あし, I believe. Cypher, thanks for explaining! The linked question is essentially the same as mine (just a bit more complex).

Comment: Ah! It reminds me of 'にんげんっていいな' http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mxrUOqUK4mE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a verb -- it's the usual quotative って. The meaning is hence something like "These things called feet are neat, aren't they. Let's have a run!"